# How to change this to use recursion from a separate function and pointers

Tags: c, pointers, recursion

I have this cipher problem and I want to change it so it uses recursion. I want to swap out the for loop here to be a recursive call. This should preferably be done in a separate void function that can be again called in main. I know recursion isn't always the best method so I'd be interested in approaches too.

```
int main(void) {
char str1[100] = "Test...";
char pos;
int i;
int shift = 1;

for (i = 0; str1[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
    pos = str1[i];

    if (pos >= 'a' && pos <= 'z') {
        if (pos % 2 == 0) {
            pos = pos + shift;

            if (pos > 'z') {
                pos = pos - 'z' + 'a' - 1;
            }
            if (pos < 'a') {
                pos = pos - 'a' + 'z' + 1;
            }
            str1[i] = pos;
        }
        else if (pos % 2 != 0) {
            pos = pos - shift;

            if (pos > 'z') {
                pos = pos - 'z' + 'a' - 1;
            }
            if (pos < 'a') {
                pos = pos - 'a' + 'z' + 1;
            }
            str1[i] = pos;
        }
    }
}

printf("Encrypted message: %s", str1);

return 0;
}
```

Super new to C and programming in general so I apologize if any code seems low level. I'm just trying to understand the math behind recursion.

Comment: Recursion is totally inappropriate for this task. There is nothing to divide / conquer / reduce / simplify here. Your cipher can operate on any character in any order, and the result will be the same provided you visit every character once. If anything, a more useful approach is to parallelize it, if you have very large (millions+) of characters to encode. If you want to study recursion in C, find a task for which recursion is actually appropriate (_e.g_ binary search, sorting, graph traversal, space segmentation, clustering).

Comment: Recursion is best applied when _drilling down_ has consequences that are passed _up_ through the levels. This code, iteratively altering a single character, is not that type of problem. Rewriting this to use recursion would be pointless. I suggest you try coding a Fibonacci number calculator, instead. Another suggestion: Populate a BST from a sorted array of data (ints or strings). THAT is a nice recursive problem...

Comment: _I want to change it so it uses recursion._ Why??? _I know recursion isn't always the best method so I'd be interested in approaches too._ This is a _bad/poor_ use of recursion. Recursion is an advanced topic. IMO, based on your code, you need to improve your general coding skill level first. For example, you don't seem to know how to migrate the non-recursive code you _do_ have into a reusable function (callable from `main`). Since it's largely a copy-and-paste to do that, I'd hit stop on recursion until you're comfortable with basic editing/refactoring and modularization.

Comment: @Fe2O3, Adding data to a sorted BST doesn't require recursion. You're only interested in one branch, so it's like navigating a linked list. However, balanced trees might benefit from recursion.

Comment: @ikegami True 'nuff... But "building" a BST from a sorted array is a nice beginner's project to play with a recursive function and its parameters... Why not just search the array?? I have an application that periodically loads a sorted list of records (then makes the BST), adds a few nodes, expires others (not written back) and using a 'tree' is a simple solution... Cheers! :-)

Comment: @Fe2O3, Yes, it's a nice exercise, but not one that uses recursion.

Comment: @ikegami "_but not one that uses recursion_" If you say so...

Comment: @Fe2O3, I do, and [so does Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Iterative_search). You can convert any loop, including the one in the OP, into recursion. Discounting such perverse cases aside --which was the point you were making-- no recursion is needed to traverse a BST. Like I said above, traversing a BST is [identical to traversing a linked list](https://gist.github.com/ikegami/f104ab458ed961b8d5a5f1d515c22e03). Using recursion would be dumb. A balanced BST is possibly another story.

Comment: @ikegami Please scroll back to re-read my comment where I suggest **populating** a BST from a sorted array is a nice recursive problem for the OP. **Searching** (and inserting) is another function altogether. You're objecting to something that is not what I suggested...

Comment: @Fe2O3 Creating a fresh tree from a sorted array efficiently does not require any recursion either. You'd always be adding to the right pointer of the last node you created. You'd literally building a linked list. Recursion only comes into play if you want a balanced BST, if you want to add a sorted array to an existing tree efficiently, if you want to merge two BSTs, etc.

Comment: @ikegami For your pleasure: `node_t *build( size_t min, size_t max, node_t l[] ) { node_t *nu = calloc( 1, sizeof *nu ); size_t mid = (min + max)/2; nu->payload = &l[mid]; if( min < mid ) nu->lft = build( min, mid-1, l ); if( mid < max ) nu->rgt = build( mid+1, max, l ); return nu; }` Compact and recursive... Have a good day. SO doesn't like these ongoing exchanges...

Comment: @Fe2O3, Straw man. We already know recursion *can* be used. This has been said multiple times.  Just like recursion can be used for the OP. It's just stupid to use it for those uses. You said this would be an not stupid alternative, but it isn't. A simple loop would suffice. `while ( n-- ) { *node_pp = (*node_pp)->right = BST_new( *(a++) ); }` You think your approach is simple and compact?! You appear to be create a *balanced* BST, not a BST. Right in my first comment I suggested that might have been what you meant. But no, you doubled and tripled down on your error instead.

Comment: @ikegami ... whatever...

Answer (score 1):

As the commenters on your post have pointed out, it's good to note that a recursive implementation may not be the best approach for this situation. However, I've provided an example implementation while trying to keep things simple.

Things to note:

- Notice how the "int i" from your for loop is now passed as a parameter to our recursive function!
- The terms: "Base case" and "Kickstart", which have comments explaining them.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// i = counter, just like from the for loop
void RecursiveFunction(char *str1, int shift, size_t length, int i)
{
  // The "base case" is the situation where recursion should stop
  // Base case: We finished looking through the string
  if(length <= i)
  {
    // Notice how we didn't call RecursiveFunction(...), so we've stopped recursion
    return;
  }

  // The char we're looking at this recursion, like you did in your for loop.
  char pos = str1[i];

  // Check that the letter we're looking at this recursion is a-z
  if(pos >= 'a' && pos <= 'z')
  {
    if(pos % 2 == 0)
    {
      // If pos is even, add shift
      pos = pos + shift;
    }
    else
    {
      // If pos is odd, subtract shift
      pos = pos - shift;
    }

    // Encrypt our secret message!
    if(pos > 'z')
    {
      pos = pos - 'z' + 'a' - 1;
    }
    else if(pos < 'a')
    {
      pos = pos - 'a' + 'z' + 1;
    }
    str1[i] = pos;
  }

  // Start the next iteration
  RecursiveFunction(str1, shift, length, i + 1);
}

// This function is a "kickstarter." It starts our recursion from the given input!
void KickstartRecursion(char *str1, int shift)
{
  // The user should only have to provide us with the string (str1) and the shift (shift)
  // that they want. They shouldn't have to do "strlen(str1), 0"
  // That's what the kickstart function is for!

  // strlen = get the length of a string
  // The "0" is like setting our int i to 0 in a for loop
  RecursiveFunction(str1, shift, strlen(str1), 0);
}

int main()
{
  // Note: You don't need to set the length of a string when it's defined in your code.
  // This is because the compiler already knows how big to make the array of chars, as
  // it can base the size off of what str1 was initially defined to
  char str1[] = "Test...";
  int shift = 1;

  KickstartRecursion(str1, shift);

  printf("Encrypted message: %s", str1);
}
```

Also, something interesting to think about: How could I remove the "int i" from RecursiveFunction?

Hint:

> str1 in RecursiveFunction is a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

If you must use recursion, here's something that could work for you, it outputs the same result as your function (although I think that your character encryption part is not working as you think it should):

```
char encryptChar (char c)
{
    const int shift = 1;
    
    if (c < 'a' || c > 'z')
        return c; //nothing to do
    if (c % 2 == 0)
        c += shift;
    else
        c -= shift;
    return c;
}

void encryptString (char * pStrIn, char * pStrOut, int iStrPos)
{
    if (pStrIn[iStrPos] == 0)
        return;
    pStrOut[iStrPos] = encryptChar(pStrIn[iStrPos]);
    iStrPos++;
    encryptString(pStrIn, pStrOut, iStrPos);
}

int main() {

    char str1[100] = "Test...";
    char strEncrypt [100] = "";
    encryptString(str1, strEncrypt, 0);
    printf("Encrypted message: %s", strEncrypt);

    return 0;
}
```

This outputs: `Encrypted message: Tdru...`